# Record is not loading to the Datatable using php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am creating the simple crud system using php. when i load the to the datatable data is not loading.when i show the error on console  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
i am tring to solve out this problem since yesterday but i couldn't

**Table**

```
<table id="tbl-category" class="table table-responsive table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
               width="100%">
                <caption> Products</caption>
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Patient No</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Address</th>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
 function get_all() {
        $('#tbl-category').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        var oTable = $('#tbl-category').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": 'all_category.php',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "patientno" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "phone" },
                { "data": "address" },


            ]
        })

    }
```

**all_category.php Page**

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select patientno,name,phone,address from patient order by patientno DESC ");


if ($stmt->execute()) {
$stmt->bind_result($patientno,$name,$phone,$address);
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {

    $output[] = array ("patientno"=>$patientno, "name"=>$name,"phone"=>$phone,"address"=>$address);
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

}
$stmt->close();

Comment: Try to execute `$stmt->bind_result($patientno,$name,$phone,$address);` after `$stmt->execute()` in `all_category.php`.

Comment: i did but error displayed now DataTables warning: table id=tbl-category - Invalid JSON response.i edited code above what you said to me

Comment: Execute `$stmt->bind_result($patientno,$name,$phone,$address);` after `$stmt->execute()`  and before `$stmt->fetch()` in `all_category.php`

Comment: i tried sir but same error is displayed

Comment: Do you have rows in your table?

Comment: yes................